# Application upload in google play show error Unoptimized Apk

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have tried to upload `apk` in `playstore` but this error occurs :

[image]

Comment: Please have a look to how to ask

Answer (score 0):

The solution is clearly given in the screenshot. google is enforcing the developers to use App bundle instead of APK. It will reduce the size of APK.
Instead of generating .apk file genrate .aab file and upload it.